# java System.out.print format style

Tags: java, printing

```
System.out.println(tree.item +"\t\t\t"+tree.list);
```

> ```
> as            [26, 27, 38]
> associated            [1]
> at            [17, 18] 
> attack        [10]
> ```

But i want print like this

> ```
> as            [26, 27, 38]
> associated    [1]
> at            [17, 18] 
> attack        [10]
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show some research. Read the docs. hint: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: This is an awesome question.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont have access to the code you want to but I can suggest to use the **-**
which means basically left indentation

## Example:

```
String[] item = new String[] { "Audi", "BMW", "VW", "Ferrari", "Cherry QQ" };
float[] price = new float[] { 18000.0f, 24000.0f, 2100.50f, 786400.1f, 120.70f };

for (int i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%2d. %-10s €%.2f\n", i + 1, item[i], price[i]);
}
```

the result will look left justified like

[image]